# Overwrite of Kafka Version in Spring Boot fails for some dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, maven, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a fresh Spring Boot 2.6.3 Java 11 application with a Spring Kafka Dependency (generated with [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.6.3&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=spring-kafka-demo&name=spring-kafka-demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.spring-kafka-demo&dependencies=kafka)).

By default Kafka 3.0.0 is is used. I want to change the Kafka version to 3.1.0 and added

```
<kafka.version>3.1.0</kafka.version>
```

to the property section. The most Kafka libs are resolved in version 3.1.0 now, but not all (above all, dependencies in the test scope are not correctly resolved):

```
$ mvn dependency:resolve | grep kafka
[INFO] -------------------< com.example:spring-kafka-demo >--------------------
[INFO] Building spring-kafka-demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:resolve (default-cli) @ spring-kafka-demo ---
[INFO] Can't extract module name from kafka_2.13-3.1.0.jar: kafka.2.13: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from kafka_2.13-3.0.0-test.jar: kafka.2.13: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO]    org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.8.2:compile -- module spring.kafka [auto]
[INFO]    org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:3.1.0:compile -- module kafka.clients (auto)
[INFO]    org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:jar:2.8.2:test -- module spring.kafka.test [auto]
[INFO]    org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:test:3.0.0:test -- module kafka.clients (auto)
[INFO]    org.apache.kafka:kafka-metadata:jar:3.1.0:test -- module kafka.metadata (auto)
[INFO]    org.apache.kafka:kafka-server-common:jar:3.1.0:test -- module kafka.server.common (auto)
[INFO]    org.apache.kafka:kafka-raft:jar:3.1.0:test -- module kafka.raft (auto)
[INFO]    org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-test-utils:jar:3.1.0:test -- module kafka.streams.test.utils (auto)
[INFO]    org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:3.1.0:test -- module kafka.streams (auto)
[INFO]    org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO]    org.apache.kafka:kafka-storage:jar:3.1.0:test -- module kafka.storage (auto)
[INFO]    org.apache.kafka:kafka-storage-api:jar:3.1.0:test -- module kafka.storage.api (auto)
[INFO]    org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:jar:test:3.0.0:test
```

The error messages at the beginning are interesting. Does it perhaps have something to do with that? Is it a Kafka rather than a Spring Boot problem?

---

This is the pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-kafka-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kafka.version>3.1.0</kafka.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: That's not an error. It's only a hint that those component could not be used as a Java module (based on the naming!!). That means those components do not have at least an automatic module name defined on their own..So you use Module system means do you have a `module-info.java` in your code?

Comment: Ah sorry misread that... please show the pom file ... ?

Comment: You should really wait for the Spring team to update, 3.0 clients will still work with 3.1 brokers, too, but it appears there's a different property for `kafka_...-test.jar` classified jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs section on overriding dependencies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#update-deps)

You could manually add the one it's looking for

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
        <classifier>test</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>${kafka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Right. See the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#update-deps

Comment: It is not that the dependency would not be found - it comes with spring-kafka-test but in the wrong version. And the question is, why overriding the version property does not work for these dependencies. But in the link that Artem provides it seems to be proven that this does not work (what is a pity). So thanks for the link. I guess I will have to go with this workaround then.

Comment: Please put the link to https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.2/reference/html/#update-deps in your answer and the workaround it provides. I am happy to accept your answer then.

Comment: See here for more background why just a property is not enough: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29023. This answer is correct: our comments just improves it. I don't see reason in hijacking.

Comment: Add the end it turned out that updating to Kafka 3.1.0 is not that simple. Also Spring Kafka has to be updated to the upcoming release 2.8.3. See spring-kafka issue [#2091](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2091). So I have to downgrade Kafka as mentioned in the posted link.